# Idle CPU utilization on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there a reason why Google Developer Console shows 4-5% CPU utilization for my idle Debian Linux VM even though the VM itself claims it is 100% idle?

Comment: I've also noticed this, and so far don't have a plausible explanation.

Comment: I have also noticed this https://www.evernote.com/shard/s164/sh/589c41c1-cfda-4632-a6c9-0563dd0c192a/d3996b5dee4c88071cc077c9fd4fccad Our previous iaas provider had a similiar issue (running vmware esx). I guess only Google could answer your question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CPU usage in Google Cloud Console is not that of the instance, but the CPU usage of the container managing it. This container is in charge of providing the virtualization services to the instance and collecting all the metrics. So, the Google Cloud Console CPU utilization shows the aggregate CPU usage for both the container and the instance.