# Constant CPU usage and periodical API requests on Compute Engine Instance

Tags: google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Recently I have deployed a Compute Engine instance developed from LAMP template.
A few days after deployment I started to see constant CPU usage (~8%) and also periodical API requests (each ~30 seconds).
I have not performed any API activity (haven't created any applications) and I see ZERO CPU usage inside the VM.
[image: Dashboard]

Any ideas what is happenning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Idle CPU utilization on Google Compute Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938520/idle-cpu-utilization-on-google-compute-engine)

Comment: I think it mainly causes by using several wordpress sites on same machine with very limited resources. before i was running them there was 0 cpu utilization as appears on graphs below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API requests solved by redeploying the whole machine, but the CPU usage still remains around 8%