# Constant CPU usage on Compute Engine Instance

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Recently I have deployed a Compute Engine instance developed from LAMP template. A few days after deployment I started to see constant CPU usage (~8%). I have not performed any API activity (haven't created any applications) and I see ZERO CPU usage inside the VM (top/mpstat and etc.). 
[image]

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938520/idle-cpu-utilization-on-google-compute-engine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constant CPU usage and periodical API requests on Compute Engine Instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648117/constant-cpu-usage-and-periodical-api-requests-on-compute-engine-instance)

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned here: [Idle CPU utilization on Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938520/idle-cpu-utilization-on-google-compute-engine)

> *"The CPU usage in Google Developer Console is not that of the instance, but the CPU usage of the container managing it. This
>   container is in charge of providing the virtualization services to the
>   instance and collecting all the metrics. So, the Google Developer
>   Console CPU utilization shows the aggregate CPU usage for both the
>   container and the instance."*