# Why is Google Compute Engine CPU usage higher than expected?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following the container engine walkthrough and I see that my VM Instance has a min CPU usage of ~80%. However, if I ssh into this box and run 'top' I see a much lower utilization. Can someone explain this to me as I must be missing something simple. Thank you. [image: Google Developers Console]

Comment: Do you have only one instance running? For me, this overview page shows the average cpu usage over all my VM instances. If you click the individual instance, you can see the per-instance resource usage. Also, the usage may be slightly higher than expected, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938520/idle-cpu-utilization-on-google-compute-engine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known (benevolent) bug in the ingress controller that is automatically added to your cluster in Kubernetes 1.1.1. If you are not using the controller, you can scale the number of replicas to zero:

```
kubectl scale rc l7-lb-controller --namespace=kube-system --replicas=0
```

which should make your CPU usage go back to a normal level.

The ingress controller isn't doing any harm (other than affecting monitoring metrics) and will be automatically nice'd by the kernel if you run other pods on the same node (so it isn't affecting performance of your cluster).

This bug will be fixed in the upcoming 1.1.2 release of Kubernetes.

Comment: I just created a free tier f1-micro VM. It is the only VM I have, and I see CPU still spiking all the way up to 300%