# Dashboard shows close to 100% CPU load, but actual usage is different

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, haproxy

During peak hours of our service, I notice the CPU load goes up to 100%. However, when I SSH into the machine and use top or htop, I don't ever see the CPU usage go above 25%. This instance is a dedicated load balancer running HAProxy.

Here is a screenshot of the Dashboard: https://gyazo.com/010715208f81ec97c1bc9b78123fe4d4
Here is a screenshot of `top` in the instance: https://gyazo.com/afa7098331f7a3f66c018041b9be686d

During these peak times, I noticed there are some latency and this is not caused by database or my other server instances as I checked their loads and were far below threshold. I was wondering if Compute Engine is throttling by mistaking it is at 100% CPU usage or something?

Has anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: Probably not related, but how many cores does this virtual machine have?

Comment: One. It's a n1-standard

Comment: Likely same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938520/idle-cpu-utilization-on-google-compute-engine : the dashboard's showing the *container* (inc. virtualization, monitoring and metrics plus your own workload), while ssh + top only shows your workload. Still, a 75% discrepancy is WAY out of normal bounds, so please open a bug at https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list to help us investigate (and hopefully fix) the issue by proper channels -- thanks!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=281